# Help with xacro default values

Tags: ros-indigo, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I have seen an interesting tool that I wanted to use : default values for parameters in xacro

http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Default_parameters

But when I am trying to use it, the model can't be loaded.
There is some test that I made :

`<xacro:macro name="lidar" params="lidarName x y z roll pitch yaw min_angle:=-2.36 max_angle:=2.36">`

invalid parameter min_angle

`<xacro:macro name="lidar" params="lidarName x y z roll pitch yaw min_angle:='-2.36' max_angle:='2.36'">`

invalid parameter min_angle

`<xacro:macro name="lidar" params="lidarName:=lms x:=0.0 y:=0.0 z:=0.0 roll:=0.0 pitch:=0.0 yaw:=0.0 min_angle:=-2.36 max_angle:=2.36">`

Invalid parameter "roll"

This model works perfectly when I don't try to use default values.

I am using ROS indigo 1.11.20.

There is my questions :

Do i need to set a default value for each parameter ?

Is there an obvious mistake that I am missing in the declaration of my macro ?

Am I running a ROS version that supports this xacro default values ?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282115/help-with-xacro-default-values/) by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 379 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am using ROS indigo 1.11.20.
>
> [..]
>
> Am I running a ROS version that supports this xacro default values ?

you are, but you're probably not 'activating' them.

In order to use Jade+ xacro features under Indigo, you need to invoke the `xacro` script like so:

```
xacro --inorder /path/to/your/top-level/file.xacro
```

Note: I haven't checked your syntax, so it could be that even with this it doesn't work, but enabling Jade+ xacro would be the first step.

---

Edit: hm, according to [wiki/xacro - Default parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Default_parameters), this should already be supported in Indigo. Not sure what is going on then.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0